# Stone-Cech compactification of the separable Hilbert space

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compactness

Where can I read about the Stone-Cech compactification of the separable Hilbert space?

Comment: What do you want to know about it?

Comment: When will you accept the answers to your other questions?

Comment: @NateEldredge,  Maybe a concrete example of a space that is isomorphic to the Stone-Cech compactification of the separable Hilbert space. But in general every information on this topic...

Comment: "Every information on this topic" - does this strike you as a *reasonable* request?

Comment: Also, what counts as a concrete description? Have you thought about the Stone-Cech compactification of the real line?

Answer (score 7):

Hilbert space $l^2$ is homeomorphic to product space $\mathbb R^\infty$, but Stone-Cech compactification of that space is not very nice either.  Probably the best thing is to read about the Stone-Cech compactification in general.  Check (haha) your library for *The Stone-Cech Compactification* by Russel Walker.